# Subscribe user in OneSignal via proxy in QT app

Tags: qt, proxy, qml, onesignal

IP address of OneSignal is now in registry of prohibited sites of Russia.

I have Android and iOS app using OneSignal for push notifications. Before I can send notification to specific device, this device has to be subscribed by using OneSignal SDK. After that I can take playerid to specify device for which I want to send a notification.

Because of IP address block I cannot use SDK directly. But I suppose that it's possible to setup a proxy, so all api requests of SDK will go throw it.

App is written using Qt, QML and Java/Objective-C.

I've tried [QNetworkProxy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkproxy.html) using provided example with some free proxies from [here](https://free-proxy-list.net/). But I've got errors not just requesting OneSignal SDK but my server api as well.

So the question is how to setup proxy in QT app (using qt, qml, java whatever) to make all OneSignal SDK API requests go throw it to bypass OneSignal IP addresses blocking?